# "Warning: Prop `className` did not match" while setting up a theme provider in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to make a theme provider with the Context API to set the application theme, which is just a `className` on `body`.

The context it's pretty simple. On the lazy initializer of the theme state, first, I check if the theme is on `localStorage`. If the theme is not in local storage, then I set the theme based on the user system preference.

```
'use client'

import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {
  type ThemeContextData,
  type ThemeProviderProps,
  type Themes
} from './types'
import { darkTheme, lightTheme } from '@/styles/themes.css'

export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContextData>(
  {} as ThemeContextData
)

export function ThemeProvider({
  children,
  className
}: ThemeProviderProps): JSX.Element {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<Themes>(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      const isThemeOnLocalStorage = window.localStorage.getItem(
        '@matheussartori/theme'
      )

      if (isThemeOnLocalStorage) {
        return isThemeOnLocalStorage as Themes
      }

      const isSystemThemeDark = window.matchMedia(
        '(prefers-color-scheme: dark)'
      ).matches

      if (isSystemThemeDark) {
        return 'dark'
      }
    }

    return 'light'
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      window.localStorage.setItem('@matheussartori/theme', theme)
    }
  }, [theme])

  const themeClassNames = {
    light: lightTheme,
    dark: darkTheme
  }

  const classNames = className
    ? `${themeClassNames[theme]} ${className}`
    : themeClassNames[theme]

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, setTheme }}>
      <body className={classNames}>{children}</body>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

In my `layout.tsx`,I got the following code as well:

```
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

import '@/styles/global.css'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@/contexts/themes/ThemeProvider'

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'lorem',
  description:
    'lorem'
}

export default function RootLayout({
  children
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <ThemeProvider className={`${inter.className}`}>{children}</ThemeProvider>
    </html>
  )
}
```

The problem that's happening, it's probably because of the server renderization on the ThemeProvider. The error that shows in the browser, is this one:

> Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "themes_lightTheme__1ra6bom9 __className_0ec1f4" Client: "themes_darkTheme__1ra6bom0 __className_0ec1f4"

Since the server doesn't know the `window`/`localStorage`, apparently, on the rehydration, the server is saying that the theme must be light, but it is dark.

Is there a better way of doing this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The initial render should be the same on the client and server. Anytime you violate this rule, you get a [hydration](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error) error, like in your case, where there will be no `localStorage` on the server, and it's present on the browser, leading to a different initial state.

You could move the logic of instantiating the theme inside an `useEffect`:

```
"use client";

import { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { type ThemeContextData, type ThemeProviderProps, type Themes } from "./types";
import { darkTheme, lightTheme } from "@/styles/themes.css";

export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContextData>({} as ThemeContextData);

export function ThemeProvider({ children, className }: ThemeProviderProps): JSX.Element {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState<Themes | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const isThemeOnLocalStorage = window.localStorage.getItem("@matheussartori/theme");

    if (isThemeOnLocalStorage) {
      setTheme(isThemeOnLocalStorage);
      return;
    }

    const isSystemThemeDark = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)").matches;

    if (isSystemThemeDark) {
      setTheme("dark");
      return;
    }

    setTheme("light");
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (theme) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("@matheussartori/theme", theme);
    }
  }, [theme]);

  const themeClassNames = {
    light: lightTheme,
    dark: darkTheme,
  };

  const classNames = className ? `${themeClassNames[theme]} ${className}` : themeClassNames[theme];

  // This is so you don't show anything before the theme is fully set. You could set a loader or something, or even remove the if statement
  if (!theme) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, setTheme }}>
      <body className={classNames}>{children}</body>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the other answer is a very bad practice. You basically remove SSR completely and if you do then what is the point of using Next at all? Using cookies for the theme is also not very feasible, you would need to manually handle them for every page.

If you want to keep SSR I would recommend you to use this package for example https://github.com/pacocoursey/next-themes, or at least check how it is done there. It works both with old versions of Next.js and Next.js 13.4+. It uses `localStorage` and requires very minimal setup.

Yes, it uses `suppressHydrationWarning` but at this moment it's not possible to implement something like that without it.